# c++ program not launching any browser on 64bit machine

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, visual-c++-2010

I am writing a code which launches browser on click of a button but during launch of Internet Explorer or be it any browser the application hangs producing the window attached with this message.[IE ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzF67.png). In the given pic appfthook.dll is used in my application

Comment: Maybe you want to share the relevant code with us?

Comment: In the given pic appfthook.dll is the faulting component.  Is that your library or is that a trojan library?

Comment: its my library its not a trojan library

Comment: Are you launching IE from that library?  In what way are you launching IE?

Comment: no i am not launching ie from library, its launched on java side

Comment: You'll need to debug your library, or add a bunch of diagnostics, to help you see where the problem in your library is.  As it stands, there's nothing much further we can help you with here.

Comment: on debugging the file named as hook.cpp i am getting error as  fatal error C1083: Cannot open precompiled header file: '.\Debug/hook.pch': No such file or directory

Comment: Consider C1083 is a **compiler** error, I'm pretty sure you're not getting it in **debugging**.

Answer (score 0):

You can launch it as
    system("START iexplore.exe");
assuming that it's in your path. You can avoid using appfthook.dll that way.